# How to permanently clear Output in Netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans

I'm using Netbeans7.

When I run my webapp I see a lot of info in Output tab. I doing Ctrl+L so tab getting blank.
But when I run webapp one more time, all previous text appears again.

Is there a way to clear Output permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ... Probably it read from the log of the used server.Clean that and will solve your problem.